# How to make invisible game object with transparent/diffuse with alpha 0 to visible alpha 255 over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day all.

I'm making a tower defense game in Unity3D and I'm trying to create a tower build animation.

So basically, for testing purposes, I have a primitive cube with a material with the transparent/diffuse legacy shader and I've set it's color's alpha to 0 as the tower should be completely invisible when created. It has a Tower script attached to it for the animation. I have another script which deals with the placement of the tower cube.

How do I make a tower completely visible with alpha of 255 of it's material's color when it's created over a certain amount of time?

So if the tower's build time is 5 seconds, the alpha should become from 0 to 255 in 5 seconds.

**I've tried the following (Tower.cs):**

```
public float buildTime = 10;

private MeshRenderer mr;;
private Color currentColor;
private bool built = false;

void Start() {
    mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>()
    currentColor = mr.material.color;
    StartCorroutine(BuildAnimation());
}

IEnumerator BuildAnimation() {
    float a = 0;
    Color newColor = new Color(currentColor.r, currentColor.g, currentColor.b, a);
    while (!built) {
        mr.material.color = newColor;
        if (a >= 255) {
            built = true;
        }
        a+= 255 / buildTime;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(255 / buildTime);
    }
}
```

Help will really be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
[Tooltip("Time to fade in seconds")]
public float FadeTime;
private float _alpha = 0.0f;
private const float _startAlpha = 0f;
private const float _endAlpha = 1.0f;

IEnumerator Fade(MeshRenderer myMesh)
{
    for (float t = 0f; t < FadeTime; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        float normalizedTime = t / FadeTime;

        _alpha = Mathf.Lerp(_startAlpha, _endAlpha, normalizedTime);

        yield return null;
    }
    _alpha = _endAlpha; 
    myMesh.material.color = new Color(myMesh.material.color.r,myMesh.material.color.g,myMesh.material.color.b,_alpha)
}
```

Then pass your Mesh through through the `Fade()`.

Comment: Worked but not properly. The color starts off with 0 alpha then after FaceTime it just suddenly becomes 255. Can you check your code and see what's the matter with it? I want the tower to slowly become visible not so suddenly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Tayab Have you set `FadeTime` in the inspector? Either set it in inspector to 5 seconds, or you can do it in `Start()` to equal your tower built time.

If you don't set it, then it skips the for loop and sets alpha to endalpha.

Comment: Yes I've tried setting the FadeTime to 5 seconds and various other times but the result is the same, the alpha sudenly becomes from 0 to 255 after FadeTime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Martin Mazza Dawson for the answer. Although it wasn't working properly at first I got it working with a simple fix.

```
IEnumerator Fade(MeshRenderer myMesh)
{
    for (float t = 0f; t < FadeTime; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        float normalizedTime = t / FadeTime;

        _alpha = Mathf.Lerp(_startAlpha, _endAlpha, normalizedTime);
        // The fix
        myMesh.material.color = new Color (myMesh.material.color.r, myMesh.material.color.g, myMesh.material.color.b, _alpha);
        yield return null;
    }
    //_alpha = _endAlpha; 
    //myMesh.material.color = new Color (myMesh.material.color.r, myMesh.material.color.g, myMesh.material.color.b, _alpha);
}
```

Love you :)

Comment: Yes my bad, it's obviously only setting the alpha until the time was up.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson Here's how the game looks with your code: http://giphy.com/gifs/test-unity3d-tower-defence-3osxYaCazTAorHa5sA - thanks again <3